# How to display pips( tickmarks ) in noUiSlider?

Tags: javascript, nouislider

This is my first time adding a JavaScript library. I've read the documentation here: https://refreshless.com/nouislider/pips/ and thought I'd just add the demo code:

```
var range_all_sliders = {
  'min': [     0 ],
  '10%': [   500,  500 ],
  '50%': [  4000, 1000 ],
  'max': [ 10000 ]
};
```

But that doesn't work... I have a feeling this is super simple. I've been looking at examples and inspecting elements to no avail. Any ideas?

```js
var slider = document.getElementById('slider');

noUiSlider.create(slider, {
  start: [20, 80],
  connect: true,
  range: {
    'min': 0,
    'max': 100
  }
});
```

```css
html {
  background-color: #888;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!--nouislider css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://codepen.io/solacy0n/pen/NjPrBX.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    slider
    <div id="slider"></div>

     <!-- nouislider js-->
    <script src="http://codepen.io/solacy0n/pen/NjPrBX.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This similar question here has gone unanswered: [NouiSlider - how to display pips?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37994643/nouislider-how-to-display-pips?rq=1)

Comment: That page you linked tells you to include the `pips` option.

Comment: Yeah so I wonder what I put where the options comment is: slider.noUiSlider.pips(/* options */);